# is there any easy way to get any changes of tabs, groups, windows of chrome for extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

is there any easy way to get any changes of tabs, groups, windows of chrome for extension?

when one of these behavios :

create or close or moved a tab
or changed the url of the tab
or add in or out from a tabgroup

or create or close or release a tabgroup
or change the color or title of the tabgroup
or move the tabgroup

i know i could judage one by one by chrome.tabs.oncreate & chorme.tabs.onupdate etc.

but i wanna know weather is there a one action could judge all the changes one times?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't. But really I dont see why just not pick all the events you want and then call query

```js
const listen = (events, callback) =>
  events.forEach((event) =>
    chrome.tabs[event].addListener(() => chrome.tabs.query({}, callback))
  );

listen(
  [
    "onCreated",
    "onAttached",
    "onDetached",
    "onHighlighted",
    "onDetached",
    "onMoved",
    "onRemoved",
    "onReplaced",
    "onActivated",
    "onUpdated",
  ],
  (tabs) => {
    console.log(tabs); // all tabs here
  }
);
```

Comment: it's so helpful to me, thank you a lot :)